# Shorewall Bridge

Tags: ssl, bridge, shorewall

How do I create a rule Shorewall for bridging port 443 from eth0 to eth1?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `interfaces` file has

```
#ZONE   INTERFACE
inside    eth0     ...
outside   eth1     ...
```

i.e. eth0 is called 'inside' and eth1 is called 'outside'

You could write a rule like

```
#ACTION         SOURCE          DEST            PROTO   DEST    SOURCE   ...
#                                                       PORT
ACCEPT          inside          outside         tcp     443
```

This would allow TCP traffic on port 443 to flow freely from hosts on eth0 to hosts on eth1, but not backwards.